# How to position x-Axis labels below x-Axis line after reversing order

Tags: excel, vba

Chart = xy Scatter

I have a chart on which I have set a Horizontal Axis Crosses-Axis value = 200. And that chart looks as follows:

[image]

Now I wish to reverse the order of the y-axis labels. But when I check "Values in reverse order" the x-axis labels jump above the x-axis line as follows:

[image]

I'd like the x-axis labels to be bellow the x-axis line. I have been trying various VBA code and just various excel options. Such as:

.TickLabels.Offset (this offsets the x-axis labels further away from the x-axis, will not accept negative numbers)

I wanted to add a large MarginTop value to the x-axis labels, but I was unable to figure out the VBA code and the option is greyed out in Excel.

Any possible thoughts or solutions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: turn on the Macro Recorder. Do it via the Excel menus. Stop recording and look at the code. You'll probably want to refactor to remove the `Active*` and all the `.select`, but it will tell you the properties to set.

Comment: I cannot record the macro because I am unable to get x-axis labels bellow the x-axis line.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the x-axis being at the bottom of the chart, you can get the labels back "under" the axis by changing the TickLabelPosition to be equal to xlTickLabelPositionHigh.  It looks better if you also cross the y-axis at the "Maximum axis value".  This puts the axis formatting at the bottom (really the maximum value) with the labels.

You can get all these settings from the normal menus.  If you need VBA to do this, here is a starting point:

```
Sub reverseAxisAndLabelAtBottom()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim x_axis As Axis
    Dim y_axis As Axis

    'using the ActiveChart... assumes it is selected

    Set cht = ActiveChart
    Set x_axis = cht.Axes(xlCategory)
    Set y_axis = cht.Axes(xlValue)

    y_axis.ReversePlotOrder = True
    x_axis.TickLabelPosition = xlTickLabelPositionHigh
    y_axis.Crosses = xlAxisCrossesMaximum


End Sub
```

I also tried to do this by adding a dummy series and putting reversed y-axis on the secondary axis.  This gets the labels right, but then the y-axis is forced over to the far right.  I would not call that an "ideal" way of doing it.

Before/after pictures with some random data.
[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: That is very close, but in the after chart is it possible to move the x-axis so it crosses at say for example 0.1 of the y-axis? And have the `x_axis.TickLabelPosition = xlTickLabelPositionNextToAxis`. Would the x-axis labels be bellow the x-axis line?

Comment: I couldn't get it to do that.  I think setting the labels to "High" forces them to the bottom.  What happens is that the "axis" moves which is only a bold line since the labels are forced elsewhere.